# nginx.conf different location problem with docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

need some clarification because I hit dead end and don't know what to do, but first let me explain the idea:

I have simple website written in Angular as SPA and I want to add blog functionality to it, so initially I thought about Wordpress as a CMS and using its REST API, but the thing is I don't want to install it globally on server, so container it is. I choose Docker. Now by using docker composer I want to create 3 images containing:

- image with wordpress
- image with database
- image with nginx

I draw simple diagram to illustrate (yes I know it's not very professional :) )

[image]

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

Now to the main situation. I want an effect, where after typing *domain_name* enduser will see Angular app and after typing ***domain_name/wptest*** will see wordpress installation (domain handled by nginx that is installed globally for server)

**PROBLEM:**

After typing *http://server_address:8085* Angular files are served properly, but when I want to see wordpress by typing **http://server_address:8085/wptest** I am being redirected to *http://server_address/wptest* (without port) and see 404 error. When I try to serve these apps separately it works okay.

this is output from *curl*:

```
C:\Users\Lacwik>curl -v http://{server_address}:8085/wptest
*   Trying {server_address}:8085...
* Connected to {server_address} ({server_address}) port 8085
> GET /wptest HTTP/1.1
> Host: {server_address}:8085
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.25.3
< Date: Fri, 15 Dec 2023 11:41:36 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Location: http://{server_address}/wptest/
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.3</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host {server_address} left intact
```

Here I have a **docker-compose.yaml** file:

```
version: "3.7"
services: 

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db-mysql
    volumes:
      - ./persistence/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - bridge_network
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    
  
  wordpress-fpm:
    image: wordpress:5-php7.4-fpm
    container_name: wp-fpm
    depends_on: 
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./persistence/wp_files:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - bridge_network
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}"
    
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on: 
      - wordpress-fpm
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    volumes:
      - ./persistence/nginx_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./persistence/wp_files:/var/www/html
      - ../frontend/dist:/var/www/frontend
    networks:
      - bridge_network

volumes: 
  db_data:
  wp_files:
  nginx_conf:


networks:
  bridge_network:
    driver: bridge
```

and of course here is **nginx.conf** file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

        # Serve Angular App
        location / {
            root /var/www/frontend/site;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        # Proxy requests to /wptest to wordpress-fpm
        location ^~ /wptest {
            alias /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wptest/index.php$is_args$args;
            
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress-fpm:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
            }

            error_log /var/log/nginx/wptest_error.log;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/wptest_access.log;
        }


}
```

Please guide/explain to me what am I missing? Do I have design flaws? I don't know why angular files are served properly but wordpress is not.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you've setup your wp-config to work on that port? `8085` is not standard. https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/how-to-change-port-80-to-8080-for-wordpress/#:~:text=Configuring%20WordPress%20to%20use%20Port%208080&text=php%20file.,//localhost%3A8080/%27)%3B and the redirect you show looks like the port is being set to a standard one

Comment: @ViaTech I found some solution to add these line to wp-config.php so i did: define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://{server_address}:8085/wptest' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://{server_address}:8085/wptest' ); but it did not help at all